# How To Save and Reload List of String Variables With Pickle In Python 2.7

Tags: python, pickle

I am working on my PyTUI application, trying to improve certain features. I seem to be stuck with a very elementary problem. I have searched and tried several of the answers here, as well as read many Pickle tutorials.

Everything works if I save the variables individually.

I have a list called `quicklaunch_list` that contains the following variables:

`browser_cmd`, `filebrowser_cmd`, `textedit_cmd`, `mudclient_cmd`

My program allows users to change the program used for web browsing, etc. by inputting the command for PyTUI to run when the user chooses to run the browser, file manager, etc.

This is the code in its entirety.

I have been trying different things for weeks. The version on GitHub has this feature working, however it saves the variables directly, rather than as a list. I want to be able to save as a list so that the user can add new commands to the Quick Launch menu. I'd just append the new command to the list and when pickle saves the list, the new command would be saved. That is the idea. I have to be making some fundamental mistake, I've never had this much trouble with pickle before.

```
# A simple menu system for use with TTY to launch various applications
# using framebuffer
#
# version 0.1.1
#
# Changelog
# 0.1.1
#
# Added Quick Launch 
# Added Settings to change default quick launch apps
# Added Settings Save Feature Using Pickle

import os
import json
import pickle
import math

global is_savefile  # 0 = false 1 = true
is_savefile = 0     # On first run, fbtui will create one if 0 and set to 1

global quicklaunch_list
quicklaunch_list = []

global browser_cmd
browser_cmd = ''

global browser_cmd_default
browser_cmd_default = "links2 -g google.com"

global filebrowser_cmd
filebrowser_cmd = ''

global filebrowser_cmd_default
filebrowser_cmd_default = "mc"


global mudclient_cmd
mudclient_cmd = ''

global mudclient_cmd_default
mudclient_cmd_default = "tt++"

global textedit_cmd
textedit_cmd = ''

global textedit_cmd_default
textedit_cmd_default = "nano"

global filename
filename = "fbtui.obj"

def clear():
    """Clear the screen"""

    os.system("clear")


def show_settings():
    """ Show current command registrations for Quick Launch """

    print quicklaunch_list
    print
    raw_input("Press Enter")

def load_session():
    """ Loads session variables from fbtui_settings.pickle """

    global browser_cmd, filebrowser_cmd, mudclient_cmd, textedit_cmd, mudclient_cmd, quicklaunch_list

    with open('objs.pickle') as f:
        quicklaunch_list_loaded = pickle.load(f)
        quicklaunch_list = quicklaunch_list_loaded


def save_session():
    """ Saves session variables using pickle """

    global browser_cmd, filebrowser_cmd, mudclient_cmd, textedit_cmd, is_savefile, quicklaunch_list

    # now saving with json
    # and back to pickle , no more json for now

    print "about to write the following to save file:"
    print quicklaunch_list
    raw_input("Press Enter")

    with open('objs.pickle', 'w') as f:
        pickle.dump([quicklaunch_list[0],quicklaunch_list[1],quicklaunch_list[2],quicklaunch_list[3], quicklaunch_list[4]], f)


def quicklaunch_setup():
    """ Quick Launch Setup Wizard """
    global browser_cmd, filebrowser_cmd, mudclient_cmd, textedit_cmd, quicklaunch_list

    clear()
    print "Follow the prompts, typing 'default' restores the default values."

    x1 = raw_input("Command for Web Browser: ")
    browser_cmd = x1
    quicklaunch_list.insert(0, browser_cmd)

    x2 = raw_input("Command for File Browser: ")
    filebrowser_cmd = x2
    quicklaunch_list.insert(1,filebrowser_cmd)

    x3 = raw_input("Command For Mud Client: ")
    mudclient_cmd = x3
    quicklaunch_list.insert(2, mudclient_cmd)

    x4 = raw_input("Command for Text Editor: ")
    textedit_cmd = x4
    quicklaunch_list.insert(3, mudclient_cmd)


    clear()

    print "Browser Command set to: ", browser_cmd
    print "File Browser Command set to: ", filebrowser_cmd
    print "Mud Client Command set to: ", mudclient_cmd
    print "Text Editor Command set to: ", textedit_cmd
    print
    raw_input("Press Enter")
    save_session()
    settingsmenu()

def ask_restore_defaults():
    """ Ask User If They Want To Restore Quick Launch Details """
    global browser_cmd, filebrowser_cmd, mudclient_cmd, textedit_cmd
    clear()
    print "Would you like to restore the Quick Launch defaults?"
    print "Answer 'n' to skip restore and set up Quick Launch."
    print "'q' to return to previous menu."

    x = raw_input("Restore Defaults? y/n/q ")

    if x == "y":
        browser_cmd = browser_cmd_default
        filebrowser_cmd = filebrowser_cmd_default
        mudclient_cmd = mudclient_cmd_default
        textedit_cmd = textedit_cmd_default
        save_session()
        settingsmenu()
    elif x == "n":
        quicklaunch_setup()
    elif x == "q":
        settingsmenu()

def defaultapps():
    """ Change default apps used for quick launch """
    clear()
    x = raw_input("Begin Quick Launch Setup? y/n: ")
    if x == 'y':

        quicklaunch_setup()
        clear()
        raw_input("Quick Launch Setup Complete.")
        settingsmenu()
    else:
        settingsmenu()


def packagesinstalled():
    """ Report to user that packageinstall() has finished """

    clear()
    print "Installation Commands Completed."
    print "There May Or May Not Have Been Errors"
    print "Depending on your repo configuration."
    print
    raw_input("PRESS ENTER")
    MainMenu()

def packageinstall():
    """ Install needed packages """

    os.system("sudo apt-get install directfb")
    os.system("sudo apt-get install fbterm")
    os.system("sudo apt-get install links2")
    os.system("sudo apt-get install elinks")
    os.system("sudo apt-get install mc")
    os.system("sudo apt-get install tt++")
    os.system("sudo apt-get install nano")
    os.system("sudo apt-get install pianobar")
    packagesinstalled()


def settingsmenu():
    """ Make Sure Dependencies Are Installed """
    clear()
    print "|++++++++++++++SETTINGS+++++++++++++++++++++++|"
    print "|                                             |"
    print "|   1. Install Needed Packages                |"
    print "|   2. Change Default Applications            |"
    print "|   3. Restore Setting Defaults               |"
    print "|   4. Main Menu                              |"
    print "|+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|"
    print
    print

    x = raw_input("Settings Menu: ")
    if x == '1':
        packageinstall()
        settingsmenu()
    elif x == '4':
        MainMenu()
    elif x == '2':
        defaultapps()
    elif x == '3':
        ask_restore_defaults()
    else:
        settingsmenu() 


def internetmenu():
    """ Print List of Internet Using Apps"""
    clear()
    print "|++++++++++++++++INTERNET++MENU++++++++++++++++|"
    print "|  1. Links2 with image support                |"
    print "|  2. Elinks                                   |"
        print "|  3. TinTin Mud Client                        |"
    print "|  4. PianoBar                                 |"
    print "|  ------------------------------------------  |"
    print "|  5. Main Menu                                |"
    print "|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|"
    print
    print
    print
    x = raw_input("Internet Menu: ")

    if x == '1':
        clear()
        os.system('links2 -g google.com')
        internetmenu()
    elif x == '2':
        clear()
        os.system("elinks google.com")
        internetmenu()
    elif x == '3':
        clear()
        os.system('tt++')
        internetmenu()
    elif x == '4':
        clear()
        os.system('pianobar')
        internetmenu()
    elif x == '5':
        MainMenu()
    else:
        internetmenu()

def MainMenu():
    """Print Main Menu and Handle Main Menu  Input"""

    global browser_cmd, filebrowser_cmd, mudclient_cmd, textedit_cmd, quicklaunch_list

    clear() 
    print "                   FBTUI 0.1a                  "
    print "-----------------------------------------------"

    print "|++++++++++++++++++MAIN+MENU+++++++++++++++++++|"
    print "|   1. Internet                                |"
    print "|   2. Files                                   |"    # Load Files Apps Menu
    print "|   3. Settings                                |"  # Load Settings Apps Menu
    print "|   4. Apps                                    |"      # Load Apps Menu
        print "|   -----------------------------------------  |"
    print "|   5. Exit                                    |"
    print "|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|"
    print
    print "Quick Launch:  web   files   mud   text   shell "
    print "               save  load    fix   sshow        "
    print
    x = raw_input("Main Menu: ")

    if x == '1':
        internetmenu()
    elif x == '2':
        clear()
        os.system('mc')
        MainMenu()
    elif x == '3':
        settingsmenu()
    elif x == '4':
        MainMenu()
    elif x == '5':
        clear()
        exit()
    elif x == "web":
        os.system(browser_cmd)
        MainMenu()
    elif x == "files":
        os.system(filebrowser_cmd)
        MainMenu()
    elif x == "mud":
        os.system(mudclient_cmd)
        MainMenu()
    elif x == "text":
        os.system(textedit_cmd)
        MainMenu()
    elif x == "shell":
        os.system("bash")
        MainMenu()
    elif x == "save":
        save_session()
        MainMenu()
    elif x == "fix":
        firstrun()
        MainMenu()
    elif x == "load":
        load_session()
        MainMenu()
    elif x == "sshow":
        show_settings()
        MainMenu()
    else:
        MainMenu()

def firstrun():
    """ Creates a save file on first run """

    global quicklaunch_list, browser_cmd, filebrowser_cmd, mudclient_cmd, textedit_cmd, is_savefile

    browser_cmd = "links2 -g google.com"
    quicklaunch_list.append(browser_cmd)
    filebrowser_cmd = "mc"
    quicklaunch_list.append(filebrowser_cmd)
    mudclient_cmd = "tt++"
    quicklaunch_list.append(mudclient_cmd)
    textedit_cmd = "nano"
    quicklaunch_list.append(textedit_cmd)

    clear()

    print "Browser command set to: ", browser_cmd
    print "File manager command set to: ", filebrowser_cmd
    print "Mud Client command set to: ", mudclient_cmd
    print "Text Editor command set to: ", textedit_cmd
    print
    print "First Run Setup will now create a save file."
    raw_input("Press Enter")
    is_savefile += 1
    quicklaunch_list.append(is_savefile)
    save_session()
    print "Save file created."
    raw_input("Press Enter")
    MainMenu()



def check_savefile():
    """ Checks whether or not a save file has been created """

    global is_savefile

    if is_savefile < 1:
        clear()
        print "This appears to be the first time FBtui is run."
        print "Initializing First Run setup."
        raw_input()
        firstrun()
    else:
        clear()
        print "Save File Found and Loaded."
        raw_input("Press Enter")
        load_session()
        MainMenu()


def Main():
    """ Load Main Menu and Set Up Environment"""
    quicklaunch_list.insert(0, 'links2 -g google.com')
    quicklaunch_list.insert(1, 'mc')
    quicklaunch_list.insert(2, 'tt++')
    quicklaunch_list.insert(3, 'nano')
    MainMenu()  


# Load Main()

Main()
```

Comment: Works for me. To verify put a `print quicklaunch_list` right after `pickle.load(f)`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else in my code? I will edit the post with the entire file. I wanted to avoid doing that as its a few hundred lines.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Maybe the problem is somewhere else in my code?

Run this minimal Example:

```
import pickle
class Session(object):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.qlaunch = []
        self._filename = fname

    def __str__(self):
        if self.qlaunch:
            return ', '.join([m for m in self.qlaunch])
        else:
            return 'self.qlaunch is Empty!'

    def setup(self, menu):
        for m in menu:
            self.qlaunch.append(m)

    def load(self):
        with open(self._filename, 'r') as f:
            self.qlaunch = pickle.load(f)

    def save(self):
        with open(self._filename, 'w') as f:
            pickle.dump(self.qlaunch, f, protocol=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = Session('session.pickled')
    save = False
    save = True
    if save:
        session.setup(['Command for Web Browser: ',
                       'Command for File Browser: ',
                       'Command For Mud Client: ',
                       'Command for Text Editor: '])
        session.save()

    print(session)

    if not save:
        session.load()
        print(session)
```

***Tested with Python: 2.7.9***